# Redirecting Python output to a console window

Tags: python

So, what I'm looking for is a way to point Python's stdout to a Windows Console window that is already open.

I'm developing a game with PyGame, and I'd like to have all the `print()` debug infos to pop up at my second screen, where I have a Windows Terminal open. I know that I need to change the `sys.stdout` to something, but how would I point the Terminal window to it?

Comment: I don't think you can do that (write to an already-open console window). Why not just write to a log file (using the `logging` module), then [tail the file](http://www.stackify.com/11-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/) in another window?

Comment: I guess that could be a solution, if there is no way to point the stdout to a window. I guess I could write my own script to print a log file to console (tail).

Comment: Take a look at AllocConsole, GetStdHandle and FreeConsole, which seem to be exposed by pywin32 in the win32console module.  I'd still use the logging module as recommended by Martijn.  edit: not sure how you'd find the window of your existing terminal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up with this little script:

```
import os
import sys
import time


def main():
    """
    Starts the loop check.
    """
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:

        filename = sys.argv[1]

        while True:

            # Clears the window
            os.system("cls")

            print("Tailing: ", filename)

            # Opens the file and reads the lines from it
            with open(filename) as fileToRead:

                for line in fileToRead:
                    # Gets rid of the newline at the end
                    line = line.strip("\n")
                    print(line)  # lint:ok

                # Closes the file
                fileToRead.close()

            # Waits a bit
            time.sleep(0.5)

main()
```

So, what I do is I open up a console, and call this script with the file that I have set the `sys.stdout` point to, and this script will automaticaly refresh every .5 seconds, and read the file. The script might needs some tweaks here and there, but mostly it works very well.